# Why do some operators create a different type of Dataset like RelationalGroupedDataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Some operators of `Dataset` create a new `Dataset` and update the logical plan, like 'filter' as below:

```
def filter(condition: Column): Dataset[T] = withTypedPlan {
  Filter(condition.expr, logicalPlan)
}
```

But there are operators, like `groupBy`, that create a different type of `Dataset`, i.e. `RelationalGroupedDataset`.

Why doesn't Spark create a new Dataset with a LogicalPlan which can express `groupBy`?

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
def groupBy(cols: Column*): RelationalGroupedDataset = {
  RelationalGroupedDataset(toDF(), cols.map(_.expr), RelationalGroupedDataset.GroupByType)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Because `groupBy` and `groupByKey` are not transformations. They are only a component of bigger transformations which consist of:

  - Grouping expression.
  - Aggregating expression.
- Operations which can be executed on a "grouped data" are not the same as the ones which can be executed on "ungrouped data" and the other way around. For example:

  - You cannot `select` from grouped data because it is not its final state (doesn't correspond to a complete physical RDD).
  - You can aggregate or map groups if there are no groups.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the high-level Dataset API tries to be as close to SQL as possible so reading one should easily "show" the other and vice versa.

In SQL when you use "GROUP BY" clause it represents no results, but logical groupings of data within a dataset. It's similar to partitions in RDD API that are simply a way to logically partition (and distribute) parts of dataset.

SQL's "GROUP BY" alone means nothing and you have to do *something* on the grouping and hence SELECT that gives the "environment" to execute actions on the groupings.

That corresponds nicely to Dataset API's `RelationalGroupedDataset` where you have the concept of groupings specified. It only serves the purpose of defining the groupings on which you can execute aggregations and hence the generic `agg` operator.

What's interesting is that the entire dataset is one single group and so you can execute `agg` operator on a `Dataset` directly (without `groupBy` which is equivalent to calling `groupBy.agg` with the empty discriminator function).